# Particular integral of $x^2 y''-xy'+4y=\cos(\ln{x})+x\cdot \sin(\ln{x})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have found the complementary Function, but can't understand how to find the particular integral because with UC method. Please someone help me.

[image: Complementary Function:]

Transcript of image:

Q: $x^2 y'' - xy' + 4y = \cos(\ln x) + x\sin(\ln x)$ (labelled equation 1).

Let $x = e^z \Rightarrow z = \log x$
and $xy' = \Delta y$, $x^2y'' = \Delta(\Delta-1)y$ where $\Delta = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}$
so, equation (1) becomes,
$\Delta(\Delta - 1)y - \Delta y + 4y = \cos z + e^z\sin z$
$(\Delta^2 - 2\Delta + 4) y = \cos z + e^z \sin z$ (labelled equation 2)
Auxilliary equation of equation (2) is
$m^2 - 2m + 4 = 0$
$\Rightarrow m = \frac{2\pm \sqrt{4 - 16}}{2}$
$m = 1 \pm \sqrt{3}i$
Therefore Complementary function, $y_c = e^z c_a \cos \sqrt{3}z + e^zc_2\sin\sqrt{3}z$.

Comment: And now you need a particular solution for the right side $\cos z+e^z\sin z$. As that is not in resonance to the homogeneous solution, the method of undetermined coefficients should be easy to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particular solution we find in form
$$y=e^z(A\cos z+B\sin z)+C\cos z+D\sin z$$
Substitute this form in equation
$$y''-2y'+4y=e^z\cos z+\cos z.$$
We get
$$\left( 2 B\, {{e}^{z}}+3 D+2 C\right)  \sin z+\left( 2 A\, {{e}^{z}}-2 D+3 C\right)  \cos z={{e}^{z}} \sin z+\cos z,$$
$$A=0,\quad B=\frac12,\quad C=\frac{3}{13},\quad D=-\frac{2}{13}.$$
Then
$$y_p=\frac{e^z\sin z}2-\frac{2\sin z}{13}+\frac{3\cos z}{13}\\=
\frac{x\sin(\ln x)}2-\frac{2\sin(\ln x)}{13}+\frac{3\cos(\ln x)}{13}$$